# Adding metadata to DjVu

Tags: metadata, djvu

How can I add metadata to a DjVu file?

**Desired result:**

```
$ exiftool sample.djvu | grep -P "^===|Title|Author"
Title                           : Group Theory and Physics
Author                          : Shlomo Sternberg
```

It sounds like XMP metadata would do the trick:

```
$ djvused sample.djvu -e 'set-xmp sample.xmp'
```

Though I'm unsure how to create the XMP file itself -- and examples on the internet are sparse.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need xmp to set a simple metadata for a document. Just create a text file, (for ex. "meta.txt") with following content:

```
"author" "Author Name"
"title" "Book title"
"software"  "djvused"
```

And set it as document metadata with `djvused -s -e "select ; set-meta meta.txt" my.djvu`
That will set document metadata. To set page-specific metadata to page number 5, for ex. you shall change `"select ; set-meta meta.txt"` to `"select 5; set-meta meta.txt"`.

The `meta.txt` file format is a space(s) delimeted "key" "value" pairs, each on a new line.